# IndexedDB and asynchronous response

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

I'm reading a tutorial about IndexedDB but I have some doubts.

> [Migrating your WebSQL DB to IndexedDB](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webdatabase/websql-indexeddb)

Looking at this code

```
function showAll() {
  document.getElementById("ourList").innerHTML = "";

  var request = window.indexedDB.open("todos");
  request.onsuccess = function(event) {
    // Enumerate the entire object store.
    var ul = document.createElement("ul");
    var db = todoDB.indexedDB.db;
    var trans = db.transaction("todo", 'readonly');
    var request = trans.objectStore("todo").openCursor();

    request.onsuccess = function(event) {
      var cursor = request.result;

      // If cursor is null then we've completed the enumeration - so update the DOM
      if (cursor) {
        var li = document.createElement("div");
        li.textContent = "key: " + cursor.key + " => Todo text: " + cursor.value.text;
        ul.appendChild(li);
        cursor.continue();
      }
      else {
        document.getElementById("ourList").appendChild(ul);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I see every time that before I call an action/method on object, like this

```
var request = trans.objectStore("todo").openCursor();
```

then, only after the action has been called, I set the `onsuccess` method

```
request.onsuccess = function(event) {
```

How this can work?
Once the request is returned how I can be sure that the method is already running and I have to set the onsuccess callback yet?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226505/doubts-about-html5-indexeddb-async-api

Comment: Thanks! And sorry, you are right, it is a duplicate question.

Answer (score -2):

Are you asking how it is possible to define a success handler for an object after the object has been defined? If so - it just works. ;) The browser is smart enough to know that if - by some chance - the cursor was opened in the miliseconds between the execution of your line opening it and where you define the handler, that it should just automatically fire the handler then.

Comment: No this is not possible: "the browser cannot be smart enough to do that". Maybe internally the `open` call is async, it triggers an action, create a request handler and returns it immediately so that the code flow can continue and you can attach the `success` callback to this request handler. When the code flow finished then the triggered async action starts. But I want to be sure about it: if someone knows better how it works, please I wait for a complete answer.

Comment: Seriously? Why can't the browser be smart enough to handle it? As it stands, I'd say the result Request object is the one being smart. When you assign the handler to it, it recognizes the cursor is already done opening and immediately executes.

Comment: Also - are you saying you can't use this feature until you know for sure it works? This is the documented way of working w/ IndexedDB.

Comment: Look at the thread link that @dumbmatter post it, I believe that is the right answer.

Comment: I believe that is what I said - that when you assign the event handler to the object, the browser knows if it is ready to be fired immediately and does so at that point.